# How to Get a Single Line of Data From a Web Service Using Rspec

Tags: ruby, curl, rspec

I've written a minitest script to test my ruby web service. Now I would like to do the same in rspec. This a working test using minitest:

```
assert_equal('switch:off',`curl "http://localhost:8081/?action=status&devicetype=K&address=01:06:05&button=1"`)
```

How do I convert this to rspec? The web service runs standalone using sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation would look like:

```
response = `curl "http://localhost:8081/?action=status&devicetype=K&address=01:06:05&button=1"`
expect(response).to eq('switch:off')
```

You can write it as a one-liner if you like, but I think that is less readable:

```
expect(`curl "http://localhost:8081/?action=status&devicetype=K&address=01:06:05&button=1"`).to eq('switch:off')
```